# Could someone help me with Regex?

Tags: c++, regex

I need to check if all the "B" to the right and the "A" to the left. No matter the position of the "#", as long as all "B" are all on one side and "A" on the other. For example:

```
-Correct-
BBAA#
BBA#A
BBBB#AAAA
B#BBAAA
#BBAA

-Incorrect-
AAA#BBB
AAB#ABB
B#AAB
BAA#B
#ABAB
BABA#
ABBB#AA
```

Someone could help me .... I already tried but I could not 
thanks

code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include<regex>
using namespace std;

auto check = [](string &rp)->bool {
    regex reg("^(B)*(A)*");
    return regex_match(rp, reg);
};

int main()
{
    string rp;
    do{
       system("cls");
       cout<<"RP: ";
       getline(cin, rp);

    }while (!check(rp));

    cout<<"\n valid"<< rp<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your failed attempt and explain what went wrong, it will make things clearer.

Comment: I tried to use this expression but only match with the first: " ^(B)*(A)*  " ... I know it's incomplete ... but I tried to add but I could not. I'm new to Regex

Comment: If you want to match a string with same number of As and Bs in it, you need a recursion supporting regex engine. Or an engine supporting balanced constructs. What regex library are you using? Please all add all the relevant code you have to the question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I need to separate"? Do you actually want to alter incorrect strings so that they become correct? Or do you just want to distinguish between correct and incorrect ones? Either way, you should update your question accordingly.

Comment: ohh sorry... I need to check and not separate... yes

Comment: The first thing you need is a clear statement of the problem that you're trying to solve. Your description doesn't match the examples you give, so it's really not possible to offer advice on what to do.

Comment: From the examples, it looks like the `'#'` doesn't mean anything, and can be ignored. Is the rule that all `'B'`s must be to the left of all `'A'`s? If so, that's simple to write, in about two lines of code; there's no need for a regular expression here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Regex won't move the text for you it will just tell you if the pattern is correct or not. You're going to need another tool alongside regex.

Edit: this regex should work for you. It matches 0 or more #s followed by zero or more Bs 0 or more times followed by 0 or more #s followed by 0 or more As zero or more times. ^ and $ denote the beginning and end of the string.
`^(#*B*)*(#*A*)*$`

Comment: exactly, I do not want to move, I want to check if the pattern is correct.

Comment: The problem description is too vague to be able to offer any realistic advice on how to solve this problem. But from the look of things, there's only one `'#'` in the string; the proposed regular expression allows an arbitrary number of them.

Comment: It's works... thanks... but I chang the quantifier.  ^(#?B*)*(#?A*)*$